# package 'gdm' is not installed and no information available

Tags: kubuntu, gdm

I've installed Kubuntu. But I can't change the user from the login page. As it's my company's laptop I just want to switch back to ubuntu. But I can't. I am trying `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`

But I am keep getting package 'gdm' is not installed and no information available.

Can anybody help me with this? I can login(using my username and password) through the command prompt(alt+sft F2), but can't switch account in Kubuntu login screen.

Comment: Maybe it is `KDM` for `K`ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The greeter for Plasma is `sddm` rather than `gdm`. Please try

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm`

In any case why do you want to change the user in order to re-install? It would be easier to just boot from a live usb and do a clean Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am having my some important files and folder. I just want to use it. Using Kubuntu,I can't login with my username. It is not asking to me for username. Just default one.

Comment: wow. It worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it possible to completely remove Kubuntu login screen?

Comment: See how you go reconfiguring `sddm`. If no luck, you can boot from a live USB and backup your `home` folder to an external drive.

Comment: You can change your user to auto-login. Go to Settings -> Account Details -> User Manager, and under your user, tick "Log in automatically". Just be aware that this is a security issue if anyone should steal your laptop, as they won't need a password to access your files.